# Is a basic Paypal Buy Now button supported with Payflow?

Tags: paypal

A business has a previous Payflow setup. They have a workflow based on transactions coming into payflow and automating some of the response and processing.

They only sell one product this way so I would like to set up a simple buy now type button that takes the purchaser to paypal for the rest of the checkout process.

Will this trigger transactions in the same way so that their automated processing can still happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express Checkout is the only API that can integrate between Payflow and PayPal.

Read [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/).